# Azure Kubernetes Service on Subdomain Best Practice

Tags: postgresql, azure, kubernetes, service, dns

I have an Azure Kubernetes Cluster which is used for hosting Postgres server from an automatic provisioning mechanism via a tool. Each provision is a Postgres server which is a set of disk, config, stateful-set and service.

Currently each StatefulSet is configured to use LoadBalancher and therefore each provision exposes a public IP. This method working perfectly and we can connect into Postgres via IP and port. Using the IP is seems not good practice as Azure has specific quota limitation into the IPs we can expose, usually 20, 100 or 1000 depending on subscription. In addition using IP we cannot apply a certificate.

I am looking for a way to redirect TCP traffic to specific services into Kubernetes cluster when using subdomains. For example **PG_CLIENT_01** should use **pg_client_01.database.domain.com:5432** to access the Postgres and so on.

So far what I did was to create a domain name using Azure DNS Zone, create an A record for subdomain database.domain.com to point into Kubernetes cluster and a CNAME record for all sub-sub domains (*.database.domain.com) of subdomain database.domain.com to point into database.domain.com.

How I am supposed to redirect pg_client_01.database.domain.com:5432 -> ClusterIP -> ServiceName ?

Recently I came across GlobalConfiguration, TransportServer, VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute for TCP and UDP, is this something which can help?